# iPad in corporate environment

Tags: windows, ipad

Company portal has Windows authentication with SSO. 
But iPad is not domain member, so ask password on every SSO company site. 
Is there a way to setup iPad for domain authentication ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. That would require an OS that supports username/password authentication, which iOS doesn't do.